# Page init js event on mobile without jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to know, how can I get pageinit event without jquery mobile or with minimal assembly/build of jquery mobile library at which event will work?

I need to use $(document).ready(function() on mobile devices, but only this functionality, nothing else.

Comment: this question helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: Thank you. So I dont need jQuery mobile library, all I need is $(window).on().

Comment: I actually thought you don't need jquery at all just good old javascript, if you want jquery I think `$(document).ready` will work for mobiles